# I need to get the value of meta tag using lxml in python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, lxml

[Inspect of Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuI1i.png)

I want to extract the postalCode value which is in content="------"

```
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get("https://www.craispesaonline.it/provincia/lucca")
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)

x = doc.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="postalCode"]/@content')
print(x.text_content())
```

Comment: The code I wrote got messed up ... I'm new here, it is as follows:                                 
import requests
import lxml.html

html = requests.get("https://www.craispesaonline.it/provincia/lucca")
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(html.content)



x = doc.xpath('//meta[@itemprop="postalCode"]/@content')
print(x.text_content())

Comment: So what's wrong with your code?

Comment: it gives no output .. Just : [ ] and if I do print(len(x)) it give 0 . So it is not picking the vaalue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `print("itemprop" in html.content)`, you'll find that the tag is not in the HTML source at all, which means it's added in there by some JavaScript running on the page. Just LXML (or BeautifulSoup for that matter) will not execute JavaScript. You would need a headless browser engine to do so.

On the other hand, for this particular site, you don't need to scrape the postal code from the source, since if you look at the browser inspector when it's loading the page, you can see that the address information gets loaded from https://www.craispesaonline.it/showcase/rest/api/public/province/lucca :

```
[
  {
    id: 256,
    name: "CRAI Lucca",
    alias: "lucca-via-prov-salessio-1609",
    address: "Via di Sant'Alessio, 1609",
    city: "Lucca",
    zipCode: "55100",
    servedZipCodes: [],
    latitude: 43.8611631,
    longitude: 10.487961799999994,
    groceryCode: "005",
    email: "tetsrllucca@gmail.com",
    telephone: "0583/341251",
    media: [
      { url: "694/694_1", altText: "Crai Lucca", title: "Crai Lucca" },
      { url: "694/694_2", altText: "Crai Lucca", title: "Crai Lucca" },
    ],
    fullCity: { id: 4484, name: "Lucca", latitude: 43.84432282, longitude: 10.50151366 },
    province: { id: 49, name: "Lucca", code: "LU", istatCode: "046", alias: null, region: "Toscana", regionIstat: "09", temp_alias: "lucca" },
    shippingEnabled: true,
    disabled: false,
    indexable: true,
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I was told to make a python script that would check all the postal code of Italy and check at what Postal Code do they deliver and return them.